# Handle non-member function pointer and member function pointer at the same time

Tags: c++, scheduled-tasks, function-pointers, member

I want to do a member function that will call every X seconds. I did a little prototype that can handle non member function, but I don't know if I did it well, and I can't handle both member function and non member function.

I have an `Event` object, which handle the function and the delay, with a basic timer, to detect when we need to run the function:

```
typedef void (*ScheduleFunction)(float dt);

class Event
{
private:
    ScheduleFunction m_Func;
    double m_Timer;
    double m_Delay;

public:
    Event(ScheduleFunction function, double delay)
    {
        m_Func = function;
        m_Delay = delay;
    }

    void Call(float dt)
    {
        m_Timer += dt;
        if (m_Timer >= m_Delay)
        {
            m_Func(dt);
            m_Timer = 0.0;
        }
    }
};
```

Then, I have another object that call every frames each function into a `vector<Event>`:

```
class Handler
{
private:
    void m_MemberFunction(float dt)
    {
        std::cout << "A member function." << std::endl;
    }

    std::vector<Event> m_ScheduleItems;

public:
    Handler()
    {
        // This will not compile, because the function expect a non member function
        Schedule(&Handler::m_MemberFunction, 1.0);
    }


    void CallScheduledFunctions(float dt)
    {
        for (std::vector<Event>::iterator it = m_ScheduleItems.begin(); it != m_ScheduleItems.end(); ++it)
        {
            it->Call(dt);
        }
    }



    void Schedule(ScheduleFunction func, double delay)
    {
        Event event(func, delay);
        m_ScheduleItems.push_back(event);
    }




    void Unschedule()
    {
        // TODO
    }

};
```

As you can see, I have a function `Schedule` that register new `Event`. But right now, it only handle non member function. Is there a way that I can handle non member function and member function, not only from the `Handler` but also on **all others objects**?

If there is no way, how can I achieve this?

Comment: `std::function` or a C-style callback taking opaque pointer to user-supplied context as extra parameter.

Comment: Make `ScheduledFunction` the template argument and call with `std::invoke`. Or if you want to mix `std::function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE 1**
Added "call any object's members" below.

**BRIEF**

I recommend using `std::function` and `std::bind`. But remind that std::function has some overhead due to the internal mechanisms!

std::function is very powerful as there are many things you can store in it.

Important:
Using a function-pointer only approach is possible, but would cause some code and complexity if you must retain the simple unified interface.

**EXAMPLE**

```
#include <functional>

using ScheduleFunction_t = std::function<void(float)>;

class Event {
private:
    ScheduleFunction_t
        m_Func;
    double
        m_Timer,
        m_Delay;

public:
    Event(
        ScheduleFunction_t const&function, 
        double                   delay)
        : m_Func(function)
        , m_Delay(delay)
    { }

    void Call(float dt) {
        m_Timer += dt;
        if (m_Timer >= m_Delay)
        {
            // Important, if you do not assert in the constructor, check if the fn is valid...
            // The ctr shouldn't throw on runtime assert fail... memory leak and incpomplete construction...
            if(m_Func) 
                m_Func(dt); 

            m_Timer = 0.0;
        }
    }
};
```

As you can see, including the `<functional>` header will give you the template `std::function<R(Args...)>`, where R is the return type and Args... a comma separated list of fully qualified argument types.

```
void g_freeFunction(float f) {
    std::cout << "Globally floating for " << f << "ms" << std::endl;
}

class Handler {
private:
    void m_MemberFunction(float dt) {
        std::cout << "Floating around with " << dt << " m/s" << std::endl;
    }

    std::vector<Event> m_ScheduleItems;

public:
    Handler() {        
        // Bind member function
        Schedule<Handler, &Handler::m_MemberFunction>(this);
        // Or free
        Schedule(&g_freeFunction);
        // Or lambda
        Schedule([](float f) -> void { std::cout << "Weeeeeeeh...." << std::endl; });
    }

    void CallScheduledFunctions(float dt)
    {
        for(Event& e : m_ScheduleItems)
            e.Call(dt);        
    }

    template <typename TClass, void(TClass::*TFunc)(float)>
    void Schedule(
        TClass *const pInstance,
        double        delay = 0.0)
    {
        m_ScheduleItems.emplace_back(std::bind(TFunc, pInstance, std::placeholders::_1), delay); // Create in place at the end of vector.
    }

    void Schedule(
        ScheduleFunction_t fn,
        double             delay = 0.0) 
    {
        m_ScheduleItems.emplace_back(fn, delay); // Create in place at the end of vector.
    }


    void Unschedule() { /* TODO */ }
};
```

This way you can now bind almost whatever you want. :D

**Update:**
The Schedule-function can not be called for any other type that has a matching public method, e.g.:

```
struct Test {
    void foo(float f) { 
        std::cout << "TEST ME!" << std::endl;
    }
};   

int main()
{
    Test t={};

    Handler h = Handler();
    h.Schedule<Test, &Test::foo>(&t);

    for(uint32_t k=0; k < 32; ++k)
        h.CallScheduledFunctions(k);
}
```

**RESOURCES**

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind

**WORKING EXAMPLE**

http://cpp.sh/7uluut

Answer (score 2):

Using `std::function` is the way to go.  Anything that can be called can be transformed/wrapped into an `std::function`.

In your case, you could write your Event constructor like this:

```
Event(std::function<void(float)>, double delay);
```

And you can call this with a standalone function, a functor or a lambda.
Some examples:

```
// declaration
auto myDummyFunction (float) -> void;

// Calling the constructor
auto event = Event(myDummyFunction,1.0);
```

If we want to pass a member function, just use a lambda:

```
// declaration of the class with the member function
class SomeOtherClass
   {
   public:
      auto someMethod(float) -> void;
   };

// Calling the constructor
auto someOtherClass = SomeOtherClass{};
auto event = Event([&someOtherClass](float f){someOtherClass.someMethod(v)},1.0);
```

In general I find lambda's more readable and flexible than the std::bind approach.  As far as I can remember, it's advised (was it Herb or Scott?) not to use std::bind anymore, but to use lambda's instead.